# Invalid query: You must not call startAt() or startAfter() before calling orderBy()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

> Error: firebase.firestore().collection().orderBy() Invalid query. You must not call startAt() or startAfter() before calling orderBy().

In all of the queries I'm using, I am calling orderBy prior to startAt.

Code:

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.postsRef = firestore().collection('posts')
    this.oldestPostTime = new Date().getTime()
    this.changesUnsubscribe = () =>
      console.log(
        'This method will be used to unsubscribe our listener when we fetch older posts.'
      )
    this.loadMorePosts()
  }

  loadMorePosts = async () => {
    this.changesUnsubscribe()
    console.log(this.oldestPostTime)
    const posts = await this.postsRef
      .orderBy('created', 'desc')
      .startAt(this.oldestPostTime)
      .limit(this.PAGE_SIZE)
      .get()
      .then(collection => {
        const numPosts = collection.size
        if (numPosts === 0) {
          console.log("0 docs fetched, this shouldn't have been called.")
          return {}
        } else if (numPosts < this.PAGE_SIZE) {
          console.log('No older posts exist. Only listen for new posts now.')
        }

        const posts = { ...this.state.posts }
        collection.forEach(doc => {
          const post = doc.data()
          posts[post.id] = this.prunePost(post)
        })
        console.log('oldest post time was: ', this.oldestPostTime)
        this.oldestPostTime = collection.docs[numPosts - 1].data().created
        console.log('oldest post time is: ', this.oldestPostTime)
        return posts
      })

    console.log('What the fuck')

    await new Promise(res => this.setState({ posts }, () => res()))

    console.log('What the hell')

    this.changesUnsubscribe = firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .orderBy('created', 'desc')
      .startAt(this.oldestPostTime)
      .onSnapshot(this.onPostsUpdated)
  }

  onPostsUpdated = postsCollection => {
    const posts = { ...this.state.posts }
    postsCollection.docChanges().forEach(({ type, doc }) => {
      const post = doc.data()
      if (type === 'added') {
        if (!posts[post.id]) {
          // If the post is already present, do not add it again.
          // Firestore snapshot does not have simple functionality to only
          // listen to changes on windows of data.
          this.stagePost(post)
        }
      }
      if (type === 'modified') {
        posts[post.id] = this.prunePost(post)
      }
      if (type === 'removed') {
        delete posts[post.id]
      }
    })

    this.setState({ posts })
  }
```

Comment: Does your last two `console.log()`s appear?

Comment: Upon first loading, all logs are shown. When I trigger loadMorePosts the second time, console.log(this.oldestPostTime) is shown, but not wtf or what the hell. Forgot those were in there, but it's 530 in the morning and perhaps people can get a laugh :)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your db structure.

Comment: Posts: https://i.imgur.com/74Csvwx.png

Comment: Did you tried without the `desc` in both queries?

Comment: I actually fixed it by assigning the next query to a property of the class. Will add my answer at a lull in work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is incorrect. Based on their doc:

```js
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then((documentSnapshots) => {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

It's after `orderBy()`.

And I changed follow the document, it passed.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Answer (score 0):

Interchange your query to

```
const posts = await this.postsRef
      .startAt(this.oldestPostTime)
      .orderBy('created', 'desc')
      .limit(this.PAGE_SIZE)
      .get()
```

As the error suggests, `startAt()` must be called before `orderBy()`